# Django Queryset using the .extra to query many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

So I'm trying to filter a large database, and found that I need a complex WHERE clause to really accomplish the search I need. Unfortunately my SQL knowledge is very lacking, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for what I want.

So what I've figured out how to do already is the following. Say I have a Django model:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    param_a = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_b = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_c = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_d = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

I wanted to be able to search for say, all ExampleModels who have param_a equal to "A", and param_b equal to "b" OR "B" so I found I can use a where search:

```
ExampleModel.objects.extra(where=["param_a='A'", "param_b='b' OR param_b='B'"])
```

and that works great and is exactly what I want. But say I add another item:

```
class ManyToManyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

and add a many-to-many relationship in ExampleModel:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    param_a = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_b = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_c = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_d = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    param_e = models.ManyToManyField('ManyToManyModel', related_name = 'manytomanymodel_set')
```

Is there any way to query based on this param with the .extra(where=[]) method?

---

UPDATE:

So I realized I can nearly accomplish what I want with a .filter operation, but I have one other problem.

Say I want to find all ExampleModels where param_e has either a ManyToManyModel with name 'A', OR a ManyToManyModel with name 'B' I can use:

```
ExampleModel.objects.filter(param_e__name__in = ['A', 'B'])
```

But one thing I can't figure out now is how to find one that has name 'A' *AND* 'B'. Like, say param_e has four ManyToManyModels in the manytomany field, with names 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'. It's easy to search for an exact match, but finding all ExampleModels that contain 'A' AND 'B' and anything else, is there a filter for that? I can't seem to find it on the Django documentation.

Comment: Why do you use `extra`? The query you've provided as an example can be easily done with usual `filter`.

Comment: Yeah I've realized that since posting this question, but now I've run into another block -- updating the question right now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

These Q-objects can be combined useing logical operations like OR or AND before applying to the queryset.

Comment: This doesn't behave properly unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe, you could show some code then? Q(...name=A) & Q(...name=B) & Q(...name__in[C, D]) does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible...

```
ids = ExampleModel.objects.filter(param_e__name__in = ['A', 'B']).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)
```

and then:

```
from django.db.models import Count
ExampleModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids).annotate(match_count=Count('param_e')).filter(match_count=2)
```

What it does, you ask?

1. Filter ExampleModel for your param_e__name
2. Get only distinct objects,
3. Get objects id (to make another query)
4. Filter with list of ids,
5. annotate objects with count of tag items
6. filter once again, for objects which count is equal to 2, because you've only specified two names ('A' and 'B').

I've chosen to get ids first, because I was getting wrong results when combined filtering and annotate, have to check this out.

Comment: still doesn't do properly what I'm looking for. I've settled for successive filters